# What is the best non-flash, 3rd party dynamic charting / graphing solution?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, svg

Something similar and as comprehensive as http://www.amcharts.com is ideal. Thinking either SVG or even using something like GD (on the server and spitting out images). Just seeing what is out there after fruitless google and SO searches.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)? It has it's limitations, but it's generally a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/) a while ago and it seemed quite nice. Haven't used it extensively though...

Answer (score 0):

Two more possibilities:

- gRaphael: http://g.raphaeljs.com/
- dojox.charting: http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/charting/

I have used dojox.charting in my own projects, and it has worked well for me. Both libraries use SVG, with VML as a fallback on browsers that don't support SVG.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/). It's not perfect, but it's nicely extensible and has a reasonably-robust [plug-in system](http://code.google.com/p/flot/wiki/Plugins) for additional functionality. It uses HTML Canvas (not SVG/VML) and works with the [excanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) library for spoofing canvas support in IE.